# What is the best way to implement "redefined" attribute in Java?

Tags: java, attributes, redefine

Thank you in advance for reading.

The "redefined" I'm talking about is the concept in UML Specification which is widely used.

**My understanding is that:** a "redefined" attribute's type is the subclass of the "redefining" attribute's type. While the owner of "redefined" attribute is the subclass of the owner of "redefining" attribute.

**Given following example:**

```
Duration extends ValueSpecification
DurationInterval extends Interval
Interval has two attributes typed by ValueSpecification, min and max;
DurationInterval has two "redefined" attributes typed by Duration, min and max;
```

**Here is my implementation:**

1) If I define min/max in DurationInterval, I'm **hiding another field**; Actually, this is the easiest way to implement a "redefined" attribute. Anyone vote for this kind of implementation?

```
public Duration min/max;
```

2) Then I introduced the "Getter", great, the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) described "covariant return type" so this way works.
However, I have to cast the type downward to make it work.

3) For the "Setters" however, if I add "@Override", I will get error. I think this is arguable; Firstly, I have to admit that Oracle said explicitly that this is not override. Secondly, I think it is "Override" just Oracle didn't implement it yet. Am I wrong because I don't know the reason they do in this way?

4) What's your implementation on UML's Re-defined attribute?

```
public class RedefineProj {
    static class ValueSpecification{}
    static class Duration extends ValueSpecification{}
    static class Interval{
        public ValueSpecification min;
        public ValueSpecification max;

        public ValueSpecification getMin(){
            return min;
        }
        public ValueSpecification getMax(){
            return max;
        }
        public void setMin(ValueSpecification min_){
            min = min_;
        }
        public void setMax(ValueSpecification max_){
            max = max_;
        }
    }
    static class DurationInterval extends Interval{
        @Override
        public Duration getMin(){
            return (Duration) min;
        }
        @Override
        public Duration getMax(){
            return (Duration)max;
        }
        public void setMin(Duration min_){
            min = min_;
        }
        public void setMax(Duration max_){
            max = max_;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Interval i = new Interval();
        ValueSpecification v = i.getMax();

        DurationInterval di = new DurationInterval();
        Duration d = di.getMax();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stick to Java conventions and start method names with a **small letter** e.g. `setMin(...)`. Capital letters are for class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to redefine the attributes like you do in your first point.

```
protected Duration min;
protected Duration max;
```

In this way you would hide the attributes defined by the parent class. Since this is not a real redefnitiion you have to do more work in order to enforce their type. The setter methods have to be changed in order to only accept `Duration` objects. You can do this like this:

```
@Override
public void setMin(ValueSpecification min_)
{
    min = (min_ instanceof Duration) ? min_ : min;
}

@Override
public void setMax(ValueSpecification max_)
{
     max = (max_ instanceof Duration) ? max_ : max;
}
```

The reason why your new setter-methods do not override the ones from `Interval` is because they have different parameters and are therefore treated as individual methods (the concept is called overloading). In your code the original setter-methods would still be callable on objects from `DurationInterval`. The above code on the other hand overrides the parent method and modifies them in order to only accept Duration inputs (others are just ignored; if you want you can throw an Exception instead).

As a side note: You should not define the attributes as `public` because all object would have direct access to them and can put them in invalid states (e.g. null, negative, etc). Always go with `private` or if you want them to be accessible in child classes with `protected`.

Comment: Accept all your opinions. Besides, What if the min_/max_ passed in is not instanceof Duration, the min/max keeps its original value or throw an exception is arguable. Introduce a non-override setter with explicit parameter type as "Duration" is also a candidate. Anyway, just wait for another 2 days to see whether there pop up better solutions.